# why would existence of a class, annotated as javax.persistence.Entity, cause the lookup of some unrelatedEJB to fail?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, jboss, annotations, ejb

I am using a large system with Hibernate and JBoss. If i just add the class below, (no code uses it. it's just a definition) Jboss crashes on startup (when attempting to to do a lookup of an unrelated service)

```
InitialContext context = new InitialContext();
return context.lookup(serviceJndiName)
```

With the following exception:

```
Nested Exception : class javax.naming.NameNotFoundException
Nested message   : ReserveBookServiceImpl not bound
```

If I do any of the following, the server comes up fine:
1) comment out the @Entity line
2) replace the import Entity statement with the hibernate Entity:
org.hibernate.annotations.Entity

**why would the existence of an unused class, annotated as a javax.persistence.Entity, cause the lookup of an EJB to fail?**

The class whose @Entity annotation causes the problem is the following:

```
package com.mine.pojo.impl;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;

//import org.hibernate.annotations.Entity;

@Entity
@Table(name="Zoo")
public class Foo implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;    
}
```

The class ReserveBookServiceImpl is unrelated but it looks as follows:

```
package com.mine.pservices.service.impl;

import javax.ejb.EJB;
import javax.ejb.Local;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import org.jboss.annotation.ejb.LocalBinding;

@Stateless
@LocalBinding(jndiBinding="ReserveBookServiceImpl/local")
@Local(IReserveBookService.class)
public class ReserveBookServiceImpl implements IReserveBookService {

   @EJB IReserveBookDao reserveBookDao;

   // . . .    
}
```

Comment: well, I'd guess that ReserveBookServiceImpl not bound because the persistence context which is injected in it has errors. Try to understand what is not OK with this particular entity.

Comment: but if I comment out the @entity line in class Foo, the server doesn't crash  upon start-up and the ReserveBookServiceImpl when used, works fine

Comment: ..since if you comment it out, it is not detected as an entity any more, but is considered just as yet another POJO class, and so does not break the persistence context.